# Manga where the main character gets transported to cultivation world but he has all his skills from a game he was playing

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I'm looking for a manga, where the main character gets transported to a cultivation world but he has all his skills from a game he was playing, it starts out as follows:

- The MC gets transmigrated (or isekai'd I'm not too sure) to a cultivation world while playing a game
- Once he transmigrated he gains his skills from the game he was playing then he tests out his skills
- He splits the ground apart using 1 skill like "High-Level skill: Sword Split or smth"
  (there are grades of skills Low-level, medium-level and high-level)

An old guy came and asks him to take care of his sect that is dying but the main character doesn't know that. Once he arrives at the sect it's already ruined down and there are no disciples around. He goes down to recruit disciples and he gets a bunch of girl disciples. One of the disciples is actually from a destroyed sect that the main character accidentally destroyed with one of his skills when testing.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *Cultivation: I Inherite The Strongest Account In A Sect Simulator*, bit I don't think it has a manga adaptation.

Comment: No, It isn't but that Novel sounds really good, hopefully, they do get a Manga Adaptation.

Comment: Aw man... I've even answered that one before, albeit as a placeholder after the queeny found it for themselves. Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but it's not a bad question, just one we've had before. You can still get further upvotes for it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found it lol.
It was: [My Disciples are Super Gods.](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-disciples-are-super-strong)

> Ye Yang, an overworked employee at a game company, finds himself transmigrating into a game with maxed-out skills in all classes! Thus begins his life as an apathetic Sect Master who is also a full-level Sword Saint + cultivator + mage! The only downside is that his beautiful disciples keep pushing him to better himself each day...

Comment: Don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark tomorrow.